# GFS2: How rename clustername / lockspace / fsid / locktable name in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: filesystems, cluster, ubuntu-18.04, gfs2

Some time ago I created my first GFS2 to do tests:

```
mkfs.gfs2 -t cluster-test:gfs-vol1 -p lock_dlm -j 3 /dev/vg2/gfs-vol1
```

From `mkfs.gfs2(8) man`:

> **-t** **clustername:lockspace**
>
> The "lock table" pair used to uniquely identify this filesystem in a
>   cluster. The cluster name segment (maximum 32 characters) must match
>   the name given to your cluster in its configuration; only members of
>   this cluster are permitted to use this file system. The lockspace
>   segment (maximum 30 characters) is a unique file system name used 
>   distinguish this gfs2 file system. Valid clusternames and lockspaces
>   may only contain alphanumeric characters, hyphens (-) and underscores
>   (_).

After testing I want to change the name of the cluster from cluster-test to cluster-prod. First I changed the configuration of totem (cluster_name) in corosync.conf, but after that mount failed.

```
mount: /gfs/gfs-vol1: mount(2) system call failed: Invalid request descriptor.
```

In dmesg:

```
kernel: gfs2: fsid=cluster-test:gfs-vol1: Trying to join cluster "lock_dlm", "cluster-test:gfs-vol1"
kernel: dlm: Using TCP for communications
kernel: dlm: dlm cluster name 'cluster-prod' does not match the application cluster name 'cluster-test'
kernel: gfs2: fsid=cluster-test:gfs-vol1: dlm_new_lockspace error -53
```

How to change the GFS2 clustername in filesystem to match dlm/corosync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is easy (if you already know where to look; not was my case). Two different ways:

**Hardway** (my first guess):

```
gfs2_edit -p sb field sb_locktable cluster-prod:gfs-vol1 /dev/vg2/gfs-vol1
```

**Easyway** (although not very obvious/intuitive if you don't know tunegfs2 command and relation between "locktable name" and "filesystem label"):

```
tunegfs2 -L cluster-prod:gfs-vol1 /dev/vg2/gfs-vol1
```

*This is also useful if you want to change the "lockproto"*